# Calculating time difference between 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has information on races that have taken place, it holds participants who took part,  where they finished in the race and what time they finished.  I would like to add a time difference column which shows how far behind each participant was behind the winner.

```
Race ID   Finish place     Time         Name
   1             1        00:00:10      Matt
   1             2        00:00:11      Mick
   1             3        00:00:17      Shaun
   2             1        00:00:13      Claire
   2             2        00:00:15      Helen
```

What I would like to See

```
Race ID   Finish place     Time       Time Dif   Name
   1             1        00:00:10               Matt
   1             2        00:00:11    00:00:01   Mick
   1             3        00:00:17    00:00:07   Shaun
   2             1        00:00:13               Claire
   2             2        00:00:15    00:00:02   Helen
```

I have seen similar questions asked but I was unable to relate it to my problem.
My initial idea was to have a number of derived tables which filtered out by finish place but there could be more than 10 racers so things would start to get messy. I'm using Management Studio 2012

Comment: As an aside: Unless you need to include your `Finish Place` column for performance reasons (i.e. as a persisted computed column), you don't need it, since it depends on the `Race ID` and `Time` columns. For example: What is the time gets updated, but the finish place doesn't (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm to build example data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Race_ID      INTEGER 
  ,Finish_place INTEGER 
  ,Time         VARCHAR(30)
  ,Name         VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Race_ID,Finish_place,Time,Name) VALUES (1, 1,'00:00:10','Matt');
INSERT INTO mytable(Race_ID,Finish_place,Time,Name) VALUES (1, 2,'00:00:11','Mick');
INSERT INTO mytable(Race_ID,Finish_place,Time,Name) VALUES (1, 3,'00:00:17','Shaun');
INSERT INTO mytable(Race_ID,Finish_place,Time,Name) VALUES (2, 1,'00:00:13','Claire');
INSERT INTO mytable(Race_ID,Finish_place,Time,Name) VALUES (2, 2,'00:00:15','Helen');
```

A CTE with only first finshed places would be easier to understand.

```
WITH CTE_FIRST
AS (
    SELECT
        M.Race_ID
       ,M.Finish_place
       ,M.Time
       ,M.Name
    FROM mytable M
    WHERE M.Finish_place = 1
)
SELECT
        M.Race_ID
       ,M.Finish_place
       ,M.Time
       ,CASE
            WHEN m.Finish_place = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(SECOND, c.Time, M.Time), 0), 108)
        END AS [Time Dif]
       ,M.Name
    FROM mytable M
    INNER JOIN CTE_FIRST c
        ON M.Race_ID = c.Race_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min()` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when time <> min_time then time - min_time
        end) as diff
from (select t.*, min(t.time) over (partition by t.race_id) as min_time
      from t
     ) t
```

I would be more inclined to express this as seconds:

```
       (case when time <> min_time then datediff(second, min_time, time)
        end) as diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. `MIN([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY race_id ORDER BY finish_place)` gives first row's time value in the same race. `DATEDIFF(SECOND, (MIN([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY race_id ORDER BY finish_place)), time)` gives the difference.